# Modifying background image of a widget at runtime in GWT

Tags: gwt

I want to allow a user to pick an image from a list of JPGs and then set this image as the background of a Panel. I don't see an easy way to do this  using CSS. Any one got any examples of how to do it programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow the user to select an image from the list and on selection of the image you do

```
panel.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundImage( "image path" );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.panelImage {
background-image: url(properPathOfImage);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height,width****etc
}
```

Gwt:

```
panel.setStyleName("panelImage "); //This will set background first
```

Then as  @Adarsha suggested to change grammatically

```
panel.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundImage( "image path" );
```